# When should I reset the SMC on a Mac?

Tags: power-management

I want to know when I should reset the SMC on a Mac. I have a very quirky G5 and was wondering if resetting the SMC would fix some of its problems.

Comment: Impossible to tell. But since it's so easy and quick to do always worth a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SMC is short for [System Management Controller](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964).

The SMC manages hardware conditions related to temperatures and power consumption. Therefore a reset can only help in problems that are related to such.

Possible cases where an SMC Reset could be necessary include (according to Apple):

- fans running fast but should not
- keyboard backlight, battery indicator light, display backlight or magsafe LED behaves incorrectly
- power button does not respond
- closing/opening the lid does not work properly
- battery not charging properly
- system unusually slow