# Noise canceling headphones make strange sound when I touch my MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I've got headphones plugged into my desktop, and a laptop nearby that I use for work as well.  Whenever I touch my MacBook Pro with the noise-canceling on my headphones turned on, it makes my headphones go nuts, creating a lot of buzzing, crackling, and popping.

I assume this has something to do with conduction between my hands and the computer, but is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears your wall socket is not properly grounded, which may cause electrical interference on your headphones when touching the MacBook Pro.

Have a look at [this related answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32417/how-can-i-avoid-my-macbook-pro-giving-me-minor-shocks) on possible measures you can take to establish a proper electrical grounding.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue with my MacBook Pro and an old Pioneer amp. Whenever I plugin the laptop into a power socket the amp (plugged into the same wall socket) starts to buzz and make popping sounds.
This is called a ground loop and to get rid of this loop needs to be "broken".
I have found two ways to do this:

- Connect an external display to the MacBook Pro. It gets rid of the hum.
- Get a [ground loop isolator](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004E8YRS00) and connect your headphones through it.
- Ensure your Mac power adapter connects with three conductors to a properly grounded outlet and check for a stuck pin in the MagSafe connector in case the break in grounding is there.