# I'm in Peru and having battery problems and electric shock issues with my new MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, charging

I purchased this MacBook Air in late 2012, found that the initial battery life was more than six hours in the US, then came to Peru. Peru runs on 220, and most everywhere that I am, the electricity is not grounded. Although I used a good quality surge protector, something happened with the battery within weeks, and it holds only about 1.5 hours of run time.

It shows that I'm getting 100% charge, and I had a technician here in Peru check it. He thought it was charging fine. In the meantime, when I used the computer while it was charging, I noticed that I was feeling electricity in my hands. Then my partner came by and felt a strong electrical charge running through my neck. Shortly after that, my neck  spasmed, followed by my lower back, then the other side of my neck and shoulder.

I've tried various ways not to have my body act as the ground for the computer. I'm a writer and need to be at the computer for longer periods than the battery will hold.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You didn't use a converter of some kind?

Comment: The power adapters provided by Apple can run on anything from 100-240V AC, they just need the properly-shaped plug, so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at this question: [How can I avoid my MacBook Pro giving me minor shocks?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32417/how-can-i-avoid-my-macbook-pro-giving-me-minor-shocks)

The only real solution is to use a grounded power source. That's just how electricity works, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your Mac is grounded, if YOU build up a charge walking around, and then touch the Mac, you could still get a shock.  I am not worried about me, I am worried about harming the Mac.  (I don't know if that is a real danger or not.)  So I try to remember to touch something else that is grounded before beginning to work on the Mac.