# How do I stop this malware from opening up everytime I wear my Bluetooth headphone?

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, apple-music

I have Sony Bluetooth headphone that has wear detection, which automatically pauses any audio/video playing whenever I temporarily take my headphone off and restart playing as soon as I start wearing it again. Nice.

Problem is, every time it does that, this piece of malware shows up on the screen:

[image]

I don't use this app, I can't uninstall or disable it, I don't have an Apple account, and I don't want it at all, I wasn't able to find a setting to turn this unwanted behavior off.

Comment: In general, asking questions in such a combative manner isn't going to be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372948/how-can-i-prevent-music-app-from-starting-automatically-randomly

Comment: @EzekielElin: Thanks for finding that link. The top-voted answer there does not work, but the noTunes app linked by aurawindsurfing in that page do. And talk about timing, the guy who wrote the noTunes got his app in Homebrew just three days ago. I'd have considered it as too much effort to have to build and compile an app if I had asked this just a week ago. If you make that an answer, I would gladly accept it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I know that you can stop it is to use a different app to listen to your music.  Might have a nice fringe benefit of lowering your blood pressure.

Comment: `I don't use this app...` Did you even read though?

Comment: You didn't read, but you made me laugh and that probably lowered my blood pressure a bit . So, thanks anyway.

Comment: You ARE using an app that gives you an advertisement from Apple.

Comment: You said `...use a different app to listen to your music...` and OP said `...which automatically pauses any audio/video playing...` `Problem is, every time it does that, this piece of malware shows up...`, it's ***automatically*** showing up. I believe OP has NO intend to use the app.